# Configure Eclipse Plugin for Apache Hadoop2.7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, configure

I am using [this](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/47/build-install-configure-eclipse-plugin-apache-hadoop) for configuring eclipse in windows 8.1. I compiled hadoop 2.7.2; when I entered

> ant jar -Dversion=2.7.2 -Declipse.home=C:/eclips/eclipse -Dhadoop.home=D:/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2
>       Buildfile:C:\hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin\src\contrib\eclipse-plugin\build.xml

I got lots of errors. I don't know where I should find compiler output and what is `NewDriverWizard`?

> pache\hadoop\eclipse\NewDriverWizard.java:22: error: package org.eclipse.core.ru
>       ntime does not exist
>           [javac] C:\hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin\src\contrib\eclipse-plugin\src\java\org\a
>       pache\hadoop\eclipse\NewDriverWizard.java:24: error: package org.eclipse.jdt.cor
>       e does not exist
>           [javac] C:\hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin\src\contrib\eclipse-plugin\src\java\org\a
>       pache\hadoop\eclipse\NewDriverWizard.java:25: error: package org.eclipse.jdt.int
>       ernal.ui.wizards does not exist
>       .
>       .
>       .
>       BUILD FAILED
>       C:\hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin\src\contrib\eclipse-plugin\build.xml:76: Compile fail
>       ed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: It may be like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19129015/3728901

Comment: I want to create mapreduce project too ,so this link is not useful.

Comment: Added language declaration (none) to code block, fixed spelling/grammar mistakes